# checkpoints c# in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene-manager

i am making a game with c# in unity and i want that if you die in level 4 that you go back to level 0 but if you are in level 5 that you respawn in level 5
the code:

```
   {
        int currentSceenIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
        if (currentSceenIndex <= 4)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        }
        else if (currentSceenIndex == 4)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(4);
        }   
    }
```

what did i do wrong the respawn still works but i am always going back to level 0 how to fix this. I tried to follow an tutorial but it still did not work. I can't see the mistake and also I don't get any errors when playing the game so I don't know where the error is at.

Comment: Ah - "but if you are in level 5 that you respawn in level 5 the code:" - how doe that translate into SceneManager.LoadScene(4);
  - particualrly given that level 4 seems to be if (currentSceenIndex <= 4), i.e. it is not 0 based? It likely is, but then your first condition is off by one.

Comment: Did you try to use `if (currentSceenIndex < 4)` instead of `<=` ?

Comment: if (currentSceenIndex < 4) that is the solution thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you would rather want to use

```
if (currentSceenIndex < 4)
```

instead of `<=` since currently the second block would **never** be reached since for `currentSceenIndex == 4` it already executes the `if` block

```
var currentSceenIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
if (currentSceenIndex < 4)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}
else if (currentSceenIndex == 4)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public const int MinimumRespawnSceneIndex = 4;

public void Respawn()
{
    int currentSceenIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;

    int spawnAtSceneIndex = currentSceenIndex < MinimumRespawnSceneIndex ? 0 : currentSceenIndex;

    SceneManager.LoadScene(spawnAtSceneIndex);
}
```

Comment: I like the use of the ternary operator but it would be preferable to pass the `MinimumRespawnSceneIndex ` as a value to the `Respawn(int MinimumRespawnSceneIndex)` method